Error `'config' is not a recognised command` received when installing `cardano-node` using Cardano-EZ-Installer (via Jambhala command `j setup)`:
I've been working my way through the installation instructions in order to get up and running with Plutus programming. As instructed, I ran j setup and cardano-cli was installed successfully. But when it tries to install cardano-node I get the following error:
** Cardano-EZ-Installer v0.3 **

2024-09-12 07:58:29  Checking nix.conf...
error: 'config' is not a recognised command
Try 'nix --help' for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eric/Desktop/MyProjects/2024/cardano/jambhala/cardano-ez-installer/main.py", line 46, in <module>
    install()
  File "/home/eric/Desktop/MyProjects/2024/cardano/jambhala/cardano-ez-installer/main.py", line 25, in install
    nix_conf_ready = check_nix_conf()
  File "/home/eric/Desktop/MyProjects/2024/cardano/jambhala/cardano-ez-installer/src/nix_conf.py", line 80, in check_nix_conf
    nix_conf_output = subprocess.check_output(["nix", "config", "show", "--json"])
  File "/nix/store/lx8vhp4fxclp494svlfis3sb2g8z4l9h-python3-3.10.12/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 421, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/nix/store/lx8vhp4fxclp494svlfis3sb2g8z4l9h-python3-3.10.12/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['nix', 'config', 'show', '--json']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
error: Recipe `install-cardano` failed on line 73 with exit code 1
error: Recipe `setup` failed on line 136 with exit code 1

Can anyone help?
